# Problema ao usar npm install no Ubuntu for Windows

Tags: node.js, npm

Ao tentar fazer a instalação de uma dependência pelo `npm install express` tenho o seguinte erro:

[image: Erro ao utilizar o npm install <dependecy>]

Pelo Powershell está rodando sem erros, mas como prefiro usar o terminal do linux e quero manter o windows nessa maquina por outros motivos, poderia me dar uma força na solução desse problema?

Comment: Cadê o conteúdo do npm-debug.log????

Comment: Você adicionou o Ubuntu for Windows no firewall do Windows? Teste primeiro a conectividade pingando um site qualquer através do terminal do Ubuntu.